# Can you conquer 3 cities with the flight card?

Tags: civilization-a-new-dawn

We played Civilization - A New Dawn twice now,

And I must say that it is rather 'difficult' to built a new city.
Meaning that you can only built 1 at the time with the masonery card, and that you can't build a wonder because of the 'or' statement on the card.

During these 2 games, we only build like 3-4 cities, and that again, most of them were on easy (to conquer) terrain.

What troubles me then, is that it is very easy to attack and conquer cities if you have the flight card.  My friend had a very good attack, and was able to take out 4 easy cities and 2 city states in 2 turns.

So while it takes a while to build a city (once at the time, you can conquer 3 at the time by flight), because the tokens doesn't matter anymore.

Did we forget about a rule, or is this unbalanced?

Comment: Your title says "fight" but the body refers to a card called "flight" - you might want to edit them to match for clarity.

Comment: In case someone wants to help sort this out, the rules can be found here: https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/a1/fe/a1fec4bd-8ffc-4317-8175-f77c1675f53c/civ2_rulebookcompressed.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, an attacker can conquer 3 cities with the **Flight** card as long as all three rival cities are within 5 spaces of one or more of the attacking player's friendly spaces at the start of his turn. (That is, an attacker cannot target spaces that have come within range due to spaces just conquered that turn.)

Based on your description, it seems you are playing by the correct rules, although the terminology is being confused. **"Masonry"** is the first level **Military** cards. The **Industry** cards are responsible for building cities (e.g., "**Pottery**", the first-level **Industry** card).

Strategy-wise, if you're finding **Flight** (the fourth and most powerful **Military** card) to be *over*powered in your games, here are some suggestions:

- Cut back on building cities on low-numbered terrain as it makes them easy targets for attacks (the exact symptom you're experiencing)
- Make use of reinforced control tokens as they can greatly enhance the defense of surrounding friendly spaces. (Each adjacent reinforced control token adds +1 to its neighboring friendly space's defense.)
- Allocate and stockpile trade tokens on the **Military** card to discourage would-be attackers.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction.

Based on what you are saying, I believe that we are skipping a rule:
Like I was saying in my question: "So while it takes a while to build a city (once at the time, you can conquer 3 at the time by flight), because the tokens doesn't matter anymore.", you are saying that the reinforced tokens still contribute to a +1 for its defence.

Note the reason why we were skipping the defence tokens in the first place for flight is that you would fly over the defence tokens, rather than face them.

Comment: @GertDeWilde The control tokens won't interrupt the path to the city as you said and therefore do not need to be attacked first. However, each reinforced token adds 1 to the base defense of adjacent friendly tiles.

Comment: I think he's saying that he was "skipping" them in terms of not applying their defense value.